# $\int _{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z-z_o} dz=0 $ for $|z_o|>1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$\displaystyle \int _{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z-z_o} dz=0 $ for  $|z_o|>1$

Since $|z|=1$ , $\gamma(t)=e^{it} , t \in [0.2 \pi]$

By integrating I got $\ln|\frac{z_o}{z_o-1}|$ ? is this correct ? How to obtain the proper answer ?

Comment: "By integrating" you should have got $\ln|\frac{z_o-1}{z_o-1}|$...

Answer (score 2):

HINT TO OBTAIN THE PROPER ANSWER:
$1/(z-z_0)$ is analytic in $ |z|\lt1 $ if $|z_0|\gt 1$.
Apply Cauchy-Goursat theorem.
Please comment in case of problem!
Addendum:
$1/(z-z_0)=u+iv$[u,v are real functions and v is harmonic conjugate of u because in the given situation as you can see,the integrand is analytic]
$\int _{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z-z_o} dz= \int _{|z|=1}(u+iv)(dx+idy)dz=\int _{|z|=1} (udx-vdy)+i\int _{|z|=1}(vdx+udy)=\int \int_{|z|<1}(-v_x-u_y)dxdy + \int \int_{|z|<1}(u_x-v_y)dxdy$ [by Green's theorem]
The integrands on the last integrals are continuous $(u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y)$ because of again $1/(z-z_0)$ being analytic in the given situation.$\implies$ the integral exists.
Now taking advantage of CR equations viz.,$u_x=v_y,u_y=-v_x$,you get :
$\int _{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z-z_o} dz=\int \int_{|z|<1}(-v_x-u_y)dxdy + \int \int_{|z|<1}(u_x-v_y)dxdy=0$ 
This gives you the correct answer.